# Do I need a 64 bit version of Windows 10 to run Blender 2.90.1?

Tags: installation

I have a 64 bit processor but a 32 bit version of Windows 10 and none of the downloaded versions of 2.90.1 will install.  Minimum requirements are listed as 'x64 architecture' but I'm not clear if that is x64 processor or x64 OS or both.  Thanks.

Comment: Hello :). The last version with a 32-bit support was the 2.8. [You can download it here from the archive](https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.81/) (*blender-2.80-windows32.msi*)